# Windows Storage Spaces: replacing dead drive in two-way mirror gets stuck

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I previously had set up a two-way mirror with Windows Storage Spaces across two physical HDDs of the same size to protect against a single drive failure. The other day, after a power failure, I found one of the drives had apparently completely died. It didn't appear in Disk Management and running Get-PhysicalDisk in PowerShell showed "Lost Communication" for that drive. My data in the Storage Spaces virtual drive was still accessible. Okay, no problem, I thought -- this is exactly what I set up the mirror for.

I ordered a new drive of the same size, disconnected the old one, and installed the new one in its place. I opened the Storage Spaces control panel, added the new drive to the pool, and clicked "Remove" on the dead one. Then its status showed "Preparing for removal," and the % used figure started to dwindle. Running Get-StorageJob showed two jobs running ("Storage space-Repair" and "Storage space-Regeneration", both with a BytesTotal value of about the amount of data I had, and percent complete ticking steadily upward).

Now, after several hours, this process seemed to have completed. But the old drive still appears in Storage Spaces as "Preparing for removal," with 0.06% used. When I run Get-StorageJob, I still see the "Storage space-Repair" job; occasionally another "Storage space-Regeneration" job appears briefly (see below). The status in the control panel alternates between "Warning: Low capacity; add 2 drives" (when there is a "Storage space-Regeneration" job running) and "Error: No resiliency" (when there isn't).

What's going on? Why does it seem to be stuck? I thought this would be a straightforward process.

Example of Get-StorageJob output (usually the first; occasionally, briefly, the second).

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-StorageJob

Name                 IsBackgroundTask ElapsedTime JobState  PercentComplete BytesProcessed BytesTotal
----                 ---------------- ----------- --------  --------------- -------------- ----------
Storage space-Repair True             06:43:05    Suspended 0                          0 B     1.5 GB
```

or

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-StorageJob

Name                       IsBackgroundTask ElapsedTime JobState PercentComplete BytesProcessed BytesTotal
----                       ---------------- ----------- -------- --------------- -------------- ----------
Storage space-Repair       True             06:57:50    Running  0                         6 MB     768 MB
Storage space-Regeneration True             00:00:01    Running  0                         6 MB     768 MB
```